# Python Regular Expression and Metacharacters

Tags: python, regex, metacharacters

There is a variable which is:

```
line="s(a)='asd'"
```

I am trying to find a part which includes "s()".

I tried using:

```
re.match("s(*)",line)
```

But it seems that It is not able to search for characters that includes **( )**

Is there a way to find it and print it in python?

Comment: I'd recommend that you familiarise yourself with the regular expression syntax: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax (for example, `*` doesn't do what you probably think it does).

Comment: Why is he getting downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is the problem here.

You can use:

```
>>> line="s(a)='asd'"
>>> print re.findall(r's\([^)]*\)', line)
['s(a)']
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
s     # match letter s
\(    # match literal (
[^)]* # Using a negated character class, match 0 more of any char that is not )
\)    $ match literal (
```

- `r` is used for raw string in Python.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply!

Comment: You should probably mention the benefit of the `r'...'` string as well. (Although in this example, it doesn't really make a difference.)